# Select one many doesn't appear correctly

Tags: jsf, primefaces, selectonemenu

I am developing a primefaces web page. The problem i have is that when i try to use a select one menu with primefaces, the menu appears with the color of the button that when clicked shows the menu.

```
 <p:selectOneMenu id="nombre" value="#{actividad.nombre} style="width:150px">

  <f:selectItem itemLabel="Nombre" itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true"   />
  <f:selectItems value="#{actividad.a}" />
  </p:selectOneMenu>
```

If i change it to  it appears correctly but i want to use the one from primefaces
to make the interface look good. Any suggestions on why this happens, Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Give the correct doctype to your page.

Your page should also have all the required tags properly (`<head>, <body>` etc)

Validate the output HTML and see if it is validateable. (Note that not all Primefaces components output validateable code)

Check on multiple browsers and see what is happening.